# User defined array and Bubble Sort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

This code is about getting the user inputs for the size of the array, values of the array, and this code sort the array using bubble sort.
What is wrong with this code? I got segmentation fault.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int arr[40];
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the size of array: \n";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"Entered value for array before sorting is "<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    }
    int counter = 1;
    while(counter < n){
        for (int i=0;counter<n;i++){
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"sorted array is "<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing that immediately caught my eye - your `arr` has a fixed size of 40, but then you input `n` and treat it as the size. If n>=40, you'll be overflowing the array.

Comment: yes, I am setting the limits

Answer (score 0):

You problem comes from here `for (int i=0;counter<n;i++){`, because you're not modifying counter in the `for` loop, it means `counter < n` is always true.
This means `i` will always increase in size, going beyond `n`, and overflowing the array which triggers the segmentation fault.

I think you meant to have `for (int i=counter;i<n;i++){`?

Your compiler can hint at your that something was wrong, I don't know how you're compiling, but you can increase the amount of warnings you get. If you're using `gcc` or `clang` from a terminal, a good way to start would be by adding `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: Thank you so much but 
`for (int i=counter;i<n;i++){` is not what I am looking for. 
I fixed this with `for (int i = 0;i<n-counter;i++){` and my code seems to work